# Flatten column within data frame containing nested dictionaries and lists

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I have a pandas dataframe with 8 columns, one of which is made up of cells containing nested dictionaries and lists in the following format: `{'x1': {'y1': ['z1', 'z2'], 'y2': ['z3', 'z4', 'z5']}, 'x2': {'y1': ['z6', 'z7', 'z8'], 'y2': ['z9', z10']}}`

How can I transform this column so that the x-variables are melted with the y-variables and become column headers (next to all the remaining columns in the rest of the data frame) and the z-variables become the data within the cells?

As this is not JSON format, the json_normalize() does not work. I have tried different ways to .stack and .unstack, with not much success.

Comment: The expected output is unclear, can you provide it for clarity? And also a constructor of the input DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) seems to be doing what you expect:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [{'x1': {'y1': ['z1', 'z2'], 'y2': ['z3', 'z4', 'z5']}, 'x2': {'y1': ['z6', 'z7', 'z8'], 'y2': ['z9', 'z10']}}],
                   'other': '...'
                  })


out = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('col')))
```

*NB. you can control the way the levels are joined with the `sep` parameter`.*

Output:

```
  other     x1.y1         x1.y2         x2.y1      x2.y2
0   ...  [z1, z2]  [z3, z4, z5]  [z6, z7, z8]  [z9, z10]
```

Comment: Argh, did not think. to use .pop; thank you!

Comment: Upon further inspection, this does not necessarily work. The result is the same original dataframe, now with my target column removed. I believe this happens because the column is not a dictionary/list of dictionaries after .pop; rather a series. I believe I need an additional step to ensure the resulting column is the correct input for json_normalize?

Comment: @jesspi I'm too late, I see you found a workaround by yourself!

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I needed to ensure I had the correct data type within the 'popped' column for `json_normalize`, as so:

```
import ast
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

def only_dict(d):
    '''
    Convert json string representation of dictionary to a python dict
    '''
    return ast.literal_eval(d)

out = df.join(pd.json_normalize((df.pop('col').apply(only_dict).tolist())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert each entry into its own little `pd.DataFrame` from dictionary and then use `pd.melt()`.

Example code:

```
data = {'x1': {'y1': ['z1', 'z2'], 'y2': ['z3', 'z4', 'z5']}, 'x2': {'y1': ['z6', 'z7', 'z8'], 'y2': ['z9', 'z10']}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_melted = pd.melt(df, ignore_index=False)
df_melted.index = df_melted.index + "." + df_melted.variable
df_out = df_melted.drop('variable', axis=1).T
```

This will give you:

```
    y1.x1   y2.x1   y1.x2   y2.x2
value   [z1, z2]    [z3, z4, z5]    [z6, z7, z8]    [z9, z10]
```

You can iterate through rows in the parent DataFrame (through e.g. `.iterrows()`) and do this process. You can then use `pd.concat` to merge the resulting rows to the parent DataFrame.